# Keep the image after editing the form. - Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-3.0

Friends,
I'm trying to edit a form with the upload field not required, that is, keeping the images that have been added.

I'm editing this way:

```
$product = $this->Products->findBySlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
  if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
     if(!empty($this->request->data['img_product']['name'])){
        unlink(WWW_ROOT .$product->path.$product->img_product);
        $filename = $this->request->data['img_product']['name'];
        $myext = substr(strchr($filename, "."), 1);
        $path = "img/img_products/".Security::hash($filename).".".$myext;
        $uploadFile = $path.$filename;
          if(move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['img_product']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile))
            {
             $this->request->data['img_product'] = $filename;
             $this->request->data['path'] = $path;

            }else {
             $product->img_product = '';   
            }

             $produto = $this->Products->patchEntity($produto, $this->request->getData());
             if ($this->Products->save($produto)) {
             $this->Flash->success(__('save'));
             return $this->setAction('index');
             }
          }
        $this->Flash->success(__('error'));
  
        }
```

That way, I can leave the optional upload field, but if it is empty, the image that should be kept disappears, as I update the value of the img_product in the bank. Now, the question arises as to how to preserve the previously saved image even leaving the field empty. Any idea how I can handle this in $ product-> img_upload ...?

Comment: Are there other fields in the form that you need to save updates to at the same time as possibly ignoring an empty image, or is the image the only thing?

Comment: product name, price, color ... there are other fields besides the image and the path. My problem is with the path field, I need it to keep the saved photo at the moment it was added if a new one is not selected.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, it seems that when you don't provide a new image, it shouldn't be updating the record at all. You're saying that it does update the record, and overwrites the old filename? What about the existing image saved on the drive, is that lost too or does it stay in place?

Comment: Did you try to unset empty file input data when edit your post?

Comment: the image field needs to be optional. At the moment, if I choose a new image, it will be replaced normally. But if I leave it blank, I can't update the record with the image empty because I need to keep the path of the image that is already saved.

Comment: the img_field field I can leave empty, but the path field I have problems maintaining the image if a new hand is selected.

Comment: Yes, you must unset empty img_product data before you path entity.

Comment: 'img_product' => [
   'scalar' => 'The provided value is invalid',
   'maxLength' => 'The provided value is invalid'
  ]
 ],